# What operator can I use to return the 'overlap' of two sequences?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a stream `IObservable<InputEvent> eventStream` that represents a stream of keyboard inputs(KeyUp or KeyDown). By applying the *Window operator* I can isolate the duration of a held input:

```
public static IObservable<InputEvent> WhileHeld(this IObservable<InputEvent> source, String key) {
    var k = source.Where(i => i.Key == key);
    return source.Window(k.Press(), _ => k.Release()).Switch().Where(i => i.Key != key);
}
```

What I would now like to do is **find the "overlap" of multiple windows**. For example:

```
var ctrlHeld = eventStream.WhileHeld("ctrl");
var shiftHeld = eventStream.WhileHeld("shift");
```

I would like to apply an operator to find the overlap between these two sequences, as in the following marble diagram where

- K = event type, where `.` is a press and `'` is a release
- i = eventStream
- C = eventStream.WhileHeld("ctrl")
- S = eventStream.WhileHeld("shift")
- r = resultStream

Marble:

```
K |--.---.-.-.-'-'---.-.-.-'-'---.-.-'-.-.-.-'
i |--a---C-S-b-S-C---C-S-c-C-S---C-S-S-d-S-e-C-

C |--------S-b-S-------S-c---------S-S-d-S-e---
S |----------b-----------c-C---------------e-C

r |----------b-----------c-----------------e---
```

**Does such an operator exist? Or how would it be composed?**

**EDIT:**

To help visualise the actual event stream(I realise the above marble diagram is a little complex). Here is my event stream test code:

```
eventStream.Pump("a", EventType.Down); // should not propagate

eventStream.Pump("ctrl", EventType.Down);
eventStream.Pump("shift", EventType.Down);
eventStream.Pump("b", EventType.Down); // should propagate
eventStream.Pump("shift", EventType.Up);
eventStream.Pump("ctrl", EventType.Up);

eventStream.Pump("ctrl", EventType.Down);
eventStream.Pump("shift", EventType.Down);
eventStream.Pump("c", EventType.Down); // should propagate
eventStream.Pump("ctrl", EventType.Up);
eventStream.Pump("shift", EventType.Up);

eventStream.Pump("ctrl", EventType.Down);
eventStream.Pump("shift", EventType.Down);
eventStream.Pump("shift", EventType.Up);
eventStream.Pump("d", EventType.Down); // should not propagate
eventStream.Pump("shift", EventType.Down);
eventStream.Pump("e", EventType.Down); // should propagate
eventStream.Pump("ctrl", EventType.Up);
```

Comment: Can't you just have `r = eventStream.WhileHeld("ctrl").WhileHeld("shift")` ?

Comment: I wish it were that simple! If anyone can think of a `WhileHeld` operator that would perform like the above then I will accept that - sadly this will not work (it accepts "d" above and accepts nothing when inverted as `r = eventStream.WhileHeld("shift").WhileHeld("ctrl") `

Comment: So you want (roughly) `if ctrl + shift + key => key`?

Comment: I want the behaviour as described in the question, I am not sure how to interpret your comment...

Comment: Hah - fair enough; trying to rephrase your question, I guess: you want the result stream to be keys that are pressed while both shift and control are pressed?

Comment: Correct - I detect whether a key has been pressed and not yet released using the Window function, and I would like the result stream to be any key event that appears in both windows

Comment: Here is a complete sample program to demonstrate the behaviour: http://codepaste.net/2vud4o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I eventually came up with offered the compositional syntax of `x.WhileHeld(ctrl).WhileHeld(shift)`. The trick was to pass in an `IObservable<InputEvent>` derived from the **original** source, rather than a `string`, then window it:

```
public static IObservable<InputEvent> WhileHeld(this IObservable<InputEvent> source, IObservable<InputEvent> held) {
    return source.Window(held.Press(), _ => held.Release()).Switch();
}

...

var x = InputStream.Where(i => i.Key == "X");
var shift = InputStream.Where(i => i.Key == "Shift");
var ctrl = InputStream.Where(i => i.Key == "Ctrl");

// gets all key presses of X while shift and control are held
var ctrlShiftX = x.WhileHeld(shift).WhileHeld(ctrl);
```

This means that the first and last keypress of the held key are captured, but I decided that this is not necessarily a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

(note: will test/revise once in front of computer)

I *think* you can get your "overlapping window" behavior with `GroupJoin`, like so:

```
var ctrlShift = ctrlHeld.GroupJoin(
        shiftHeld,
        e => eventStream.Key("ctrl").Release(),   // "left duration" selector
        e => eventStream.Key("shift").Release(),  // "right duration" selector
        (a,b) => b.Key(a.Key).Press())
    .Switch();
```

But I can never get the `GroupJoin` syntax right from sight alone, so very likely this isn't quite it...basically, the thought is:

- from the start of events in ctrlHeld (until a ctrl release occurs)
- from the start of events in shiftHeld (until a shift release occurs)
- select the overlap (b), only presses that are in both windows
- flatten those nested observables and return

(edit: thinking further, you might be able to reuse the window selectors for the durations...)

```
var ctrlShift = ctrlHeld.GroupJoin(
        shiftHeld,
        e => ctrlHeld,   // "left duration" selector
        e => shiftHeld,  // "right duration" selector
        (a,b) => b.Key(a.Key).Press())
    .Switch();
```

Aha, I knew there was a link out there that explained this:

[The inestimable Lee Campbell on Windows and Buffers in Rx](http://leecampbell.blogspot.com/2011/03/rx-part-9join-window-buffer-and-group.html)

Answer (score 0):

The closest I have come so far is:

```
var ctrlShift = Observable.CombineLatest(ctrlHeld, shiftHeld)
    .SelectMany(list =>
        {
            if (list.Any(o => o != list[0]))
                return Observable.Empty<InputEvent>();
            else
                return Observable.Return(list[0]);
        });
```

It does the job but it is kinda ugly. If there is any answer more succinct or expressive than this, I will accept it